# Estou fazendo uma calculadora e não consigo exibir os resultados

Tags: javascript, html, funções, javascript-eventos

Estou basicamente transformando um apanhado de fórmulas de Excel em uma calculadora que vai aparecer numa landing page. Fiz toda a lógica dos cálculos, mas não sei exatamente o que faltou eu fazer pra conectar os campos e o botão de resultado.
Provavelmente tem muita coisa que não entra em boas práticas, mas é porque resolvi me arriscar depois de passar uma década sem programar nada.
Muito obrigada pela ajuda!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <header>
<script type="text/javascript">
            
            var trib_atual = document.getElementById("trib_atual");
            var anexo_simples = document.getElementById("anexo_simples");
            var ramo = document.getElementById("ramo");
            
            var fat_mensal = document.getElementById("fat_mensal").value;
            var fat_12m = ("fat_12m"*12);
            
            var custos_merc = document.getElementById("custos_merc").value;
            var custos_adm = document.getElementById("custos_adm").value;
            var custos_clt = document.getElementById("custos_clt").value;
            var custos_mkt = document.getElementById("custos_mkt").value;
            var custos_mensais = parseInt(custos_merc) + parseInt(custos_adm) + parseInt(custos_clt) + parseInt(custos_mkt);
            
            var lucro_liquido = parseInt(fat_mensal) - parseInt(custos_mensais);
            var lucro_real = parseInt(lucro_liquido) * 12;
            
            
            var c1_tributos = (parseInt(classe1_clt) + parseInt(classe1_piscofins) + parseInt(classe1_outros)) / 12;
            var c2_tributos = (parseInt(classe1_clt) + parseInt(classe1_piscofins) + parseInt(classe2_outros)) / 12;
            var c3_tributos = (parseInt(classe1_clt) + parseInt(classe1_piscofins) + parseInt(classe3_outros)) / 12;
            var c4_tributos = (parseInt(classe1_clt) + parseInt(classe1_piscofins) + parseInt(classe4_outros)) / 12;
            var c5_tributos = (parseInt(classe1_clt) + parseInt(classe1_piscofins) + parseInt(classe5_outros)) / 12;
            

            function calculo_ir(){
            if (lucro_presumido > 240000){
            var ir = parseInt(lucro_presumido) * 0.15 + (parseInt(lucro_presumido) - 240000) * 0.1;
            else var ir = parseInt(lucro_presumido) * 0.15;
            }
            }


            function calculo_ircs(){
            if (lucro_real > 240000)
                {var lucro_real = parseInt(lucro_real) - 240000 * 0.1}
                else var lucro_real = 0 {
            var ircs = parseInt(lucro_presumido) * 0.15 + (parseInt(lucro_presumido) - 240000) * 0.1; }
            else var ircs = parseInt(lucro_presumido) * 0.15;
            }
            



            function calculo_piscofins(){
            if ((((parseInt(fat_mensal) * 0.0925)) - (parseInt(custos_merc) - parseInt(custos_mkt)) * 0.0925) * 12) < 0 = 0 {
            var piscofins = 0;
            } else {
            var piscofins = (((parseInt(fat_mensal) * 0.0925)) - (parseInt(custos_merc) - parseInt(custos_mkt)) * 0.0925) * 12;
            }
            }


           
            //simples nacional

            function calculo_aliquota_parc_faixa_1(){
            if (cat_simples == "i") {
                var limite_faixa1 = "180000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "4%";
                var parc_ded = "0";
                else if (cat_simples == "ii") {
                var limite_faixa1 = "180000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "4.5%";
                var parc_ded = "0";
                else if (cat_simples == "iii") {
                var limite_faixa1 = "180000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "6%";
                var parc_ded = "0";
                else if (cat_simples == "iv") {
                var limite_faixa1 = "4800000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "30%";
                var parc_ded = "72000";
                else if (cat_simples == "v") {
                var limite_faixa1 = "180000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "15.5%";
                var parc_ded = "0";
            }}

           function calculo_aliquota_parc_faixa_2(){
            if (cat_simples == "i") {
                var limite_faixa2 = "360000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "7.3%";
                var parc_ded = "0";
                else if (cat_simples == "ii") {
                var limite_faixa2 = "360000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "7.8%";
                var parc_ded = "0";
                else if (cat_simples == "iii") {
                var limite_faixa2 = "360000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "11.2%";
                var parc_ded = "0";
                else if (cat_simples == "iv") {
                var limite_faixa2 = "180000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "4.5%";
                var parc_ded = "72000";
                else if (cat_simples == "v") {
                var limite_faixa2 = "360000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "18%";
                var parc_ded = "0";
            }}


            function calculo_aliquota_parc_faixa_3(){
            if (cat_simples == "i") {
                var limite_faixa3 = "720000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "7.3%";
                var parc_ded = "0";
                else if (cat_simples == "ii") {
                var limite_faixa3 = "720000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "7.8%";
                var parc_ded = "0";
                else if (cat_simples == "iii") {
                var limite_faixa3 = "720000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "11.2%";
                var parc_ded = "0";
                else if (cat_simples == "iv") {
                var limite_faixa3 = "360000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "4.5%";
                var parc_ded = "72000";
                else if (cat_simples == "v") {
                var limite_faixa3 = "720000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "18%";
                var parc_ded = "0";
            }}

            function calculo_aliquota_parc_faixa_4(){
            if (cat_simples == "i") {
                var limite_faixa4 = "1800000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "10.7%";
                var parc_ded = "22500";
                else if (cat_simples == "ii") {
                var limite_faixa4 = "1800000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "11.2%";
                var parc_ded = "22500";
                else if (cat_simples == "iii") {
                var limite_faixa4 = "1800000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "16%";
                var parc_ded = "35640";
                else if (cat_simples == "iv") {
                var limite_faixa4 = "720000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "10.2%";
                var parc_ded = "12420";
                else if (cat_simples == "v") {
                var limite_faixa4 = "1800000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "20.5%";
                var parc_ded = "17100";
            }}

            function calculo_aliquota_parc_faixa_5(){
            if (cat_simples == "i") {
                var limite_faixa5 = "3600000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "14.3%";
                var parc_ded = "87300";
                else if (cat_simples == "ii") {
                var limite_faixa5 = "3600000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "14.7%";
                var parc_ded = "125640";
                else if (cat_simples == "iii") {
                var limite_faixa5 = "3600000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "21%";
                var parc_ded = "35640";
                else if (cat_simples == "iv") {
                var limite_faixa5 = "1800000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "14%";
                var parc_ded = "39780";
                else if (cat_simples == "v") {
                var limite_faixa5 = "3600000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "23%";
                var parc_ded = "62100";
            }}

            function calculo_aliquota_parc_faixa_6(){
            if (cat_simples == "i") {
                var limite_faixa5 = "4800000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "19%";
                var parc_ded = "378000";
                else if (cat_simples == "ii") {
                var limite_faixa5 = "4800000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "30%";
                var parc_ded = "720000";
                else if (cat_simples == "iii") {
                var limite_faixa5 = "4800000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "33%";
                var parc_ded = "648000";
                else if (cat_simples == "iv") {
                var limite_faixa5 = "3600000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "22%";
                var parc_ded = "183780";
                else if (cat_simples == "v") {
                var limite_faixa5 = "4800000";
                var aliquota_faixa = "30.5%";
                var parc_ded = "540000";
            }}


           function calculo_faixa(){
            if (parseInt(fat_12m) <= parseInt(limite_faixa1)) {
                var faixa_simples = "faixa1";
                else if (parseInt(fat_12m) <= parseInt(limite_faixa2)) {
                var faixa_simples = "faixa2";
                else if (parseInt(fat_12m) <= parseInt(limite_faixa3)) {
                var faixa_simples = "faixa3";
                else if (parseInt(fat_12m) <= parseInt(limite_faixa5)) {
                var faixa_simples = "faixa4";
                else if (parseInt(fat_12m) <= parseInt(limite_faixa5)) {
                var faixa_simples = "faixa5";
                else if (parseInt(fat_12m) >= parseInt(limite_faixa6)) {
                var faixa_simples = "faixa6 ";
            }}}}}}}
            

            function calculo_simples_nacional(){
                var aliquota_simples_nacional = (parseInt(fat12m) * (parseInt(aliquota_faixa) - parseInt(parc_ded)) / parseInt(fat12m);

            }


            //lucro presumido
          
            function define_lp(){
                if ramo == ("at_imob" || "com" || "ind_terc" "transp_cargo");
                var classe = "classe1";
                else if ramo == ("prest_serv");
                var classe = "classe2";
                else if ramo == ("rev_comb");
                var classe = "classe3";
                else if ramo == ("serv_hosp");
                var classe = "classe4";
                else if ramo == ("transp");
                var classe = "classe5";
            }

                
            }

           function classe1_calculolp(){
            var c1asse1_lucro_presumido = 0.08 * parseInt(fat_12m);
            var classe1_ir = calculo_ir();
            var classe1_lucro_presumido_csll = 0.08 * parseInt(fat_12m);
            var classe1_unk = parseInt(classe1_lucro_presumido_csll) * 0.09;
            var classe1_outros = parseInt(fat_12m) * (0.18 + 0.0365);
            var classe1_clt = parseInt(custos_clt) * 12 * 0.358;
            var classe1_total_presumido = parseInt(classe1_ir) + parseInt(classe1_unk) + parseInt(classe1_outros) + parseInt(classe1_clt);

            if (ramo == "classe1");
            var aliq_presumido = parseInt(classe1_total_presumido) / parseInt(fat_12m);
          }
            
            function classe2_calculolp(){
            var c1asse2_lucro_presumido = 0.32 * parseInt(fat_12m);
            var classe2_ir = calculo_ir();
            var classe2_lucro_presumido_csll = 0.32 * parseInt(fat_12m);
            var classe2_unk = parseInt(classe2_lucro_presumido_csll) * 0.09;
            var classe2_outros = parseInt(fat_12m) * (0.05 + 0.0365);
            var classe2_clt = parseInt(custos_clt) * 12 * 0.358;
            var classe2_total_presumido = parseInt(classe2_ir) + parseInt(classe2_unk) + parseInt(classe2_outros) + parseInt(classe2_clt);
            
            if (ramo == "classe2");
            var aliq_presumido = parseInt(classe2_total_presumido) / parseInt(fat_12m);
            }

            function classe3_calculolp(){
            var c1asse3_lucro_presumido = 0.016 * parseInt(fat_12m);
            var classe3_ir = calculo_ir();
            var classe3_lucro_presumido_csll = 0.016 * parseInt(fat_12m);
            var classe3_unk = parseInt(classe3_lucro_presumido_csll) * 0.09;
            var classe3_outros = 0;
            var classe3_clt = parseInt(custos_clt) * 12 * 0.358;
            var classe3_total_presumido = parseInt(classe3_ir) + parseInt(classe3_unk) + parseInt(classe3_outros) + parseInt(classe3_clt);
            
            if (ramo == "classe3");
            var aliq_presumido = parseInt(classe3_total_presumido) / parseInt(fat_12m);
            }

            function classe4_calculolp(){
            var c1asse4_lucro_presumido = 0.08 * parseInt(fat_12m);
            var classe4_ir = calculo_ir();
            var classe4_lucro_presumido_csll = 0.12 * parseInt(fat_12m);
            var classe4_unk = parseInt(classe4_lucro_presumido_csll) * 0.09;
            var classe4_outros = parseInt(fat_12m) * (0.05 + 0.0365);
            var classe4_clt = parseInt(custos_clt) * 12 * 0.358;
            var classe4_total_presumido = parseInt(classe4_ir) + parseInt(classe4_unk) + parseInt(classe4_outros) + parseInt(classe4_clt);
            
            if (ramo == "classe4");
            var aliq_presumido = parseInt(classe4_total_presumido) / parseInt(fat_12m);
            }

            function classe5_calculolp(){
            var c1asse5_lucro_presumido = 0.16 * parseInt(fat_12m);
            var classe5_ir = calculo_ir();
            var classe5_lucro_presumido_csll = 0.16 * parseInt(fat_12m);
            var classe5_unk = parseInt(classe5_lucro_presumido_csll) * 0.09;
            var classe5_outros = parseInt(fat_12m) * (0.18 + 0.0365);
            var classe5_clt = parseInt(custos_clt) * 12 * 0.358;
            var classe5_total_presumido = parseInt(classe5_ir) + parseInt(classe5_unk) + parseInt(classe5_outros) + parseInt(classe5_clt);
            
            if (ramo == "classe5");
            var aliq_presumido = parseInt(classe5_total_presumido) / parseInt(fat_12m);
            }


            //lucro real



            function classe1_calculolr(){
            var c1asse1_lucro_real = parseInt(lucro_liquido) * 12;
            var classe1_ircs = ircs;
            var classe1_piscofins = piscofins;
            var classe1_outros = parseInt(fat_12m) * 0.18;
            var classe1_total_real = parseInt(classe1_ircs) + parseInt(classe1_piscofins) + parseInt(classe1_outros) + parseInt(classe1_clt);

            if (ramo == "classe5");
            var aliq_total =  parseInt(classe1_total_real) / parseInt(fat_12m);


            }

            function classe2_calculolr(){
            var c1asse2_lucro_real = parseInt(lucro_liquido) * 12;
            var classe2_ircs = ircs;
            var classe2_piscofins = piscofins;
            var classe2_outros = parseInt(fat_12m) * 0.5;
            var classe2_total_real = parseInt(classe2_ircs) + parseInt(classe2_piscofins) + parseInt(classe2_outros) + parseInt(classe2_clt);

            if (ramo == "classe2");
            var aliq_total =  parseInt(classe2_total_real) / parseInt(fat_12m);


            }
            function classe3_calculolr(){
            var c1asse3_lucro_real = parseInt(lucro_liquido) * 12;
            var classe3_ircs = ircs;
            var classe3_piscofins = piscofins;
            var classe3_outros = parseInt(fat_12m) * 0;
            var classe3_total_real = parseInt(classe3_ircs) + parseInt(classe3_piscofins) + parseInt(classe3_outros) + parseInt(classe3_clt);

            if (ramo == "classe3");
            var aliq_total =  parseInt(classe3_total_real) / parseInt(fat_12m);


            } function classe4_calculolr(){
            var c1asse4_lucro_real = parseInt(lucro_liquido) * 12;
            var classe4_ircs = ircs;
            var classe4_piscofins = piscofins;
            var classe4_outros = parseInt(fat_12m) * 0.05;
            var classe4_total_real = parseInt(classe4_ircs) + parseInt(classe4_piscofins) + parseInt(classe4_outros) + parseInt(classe4_clt);

            if (ramo == "classe4");
            var aliq_total =  parseInt(classe4_total_real) / parseInt(fat_12m);



            } function classe5_calculolr(){
            var c1asse5_lucro_real = parseInt(lucro_liquido) * 12;
            var classe5_ircs = ircs;
            var classe5_piscofins = piscofins;
            var classe5_outros = parseInt(fat_12m) * 0.18;
            var classe5_total_real = parseInt(classe5_ircs) + parseInt(classe5_piscofins) + parseInt(classe5_outros) + parseInt(classe5_clt);

            if (ramo == "classe5");
            var aliq_total =  parseInt(classe5_total_real) / parseInt(fat_12m);


            }


           
            function opcao_trib(){
 if(document.getElementById("trib_atual").value == ""){
 alert("Selecione uma opção");
 }
 if(document.getElementById("trib_atual").value == "1a")
 {
 calculo_simples();
 }
 }
 if(document.getElementById("trib_atual").value == "1b" && ((document.getElementById("ramo") == "at_imob") || (document.getElementById("ramo") == "com") || (document.getElementById("ramo") == "ind_terc") || (document.getElementById("ramo") == "transp_cargo"))); {classe1_calculolp()};

 else if (document.getElementById("trib_atual").value == "1b" && (document.getElementById("ramo") == "prest_serv")); {classe2_calculolp()};
    else if (document.getElementById("trib_atual").value == "1b" && (document.getElementById("ramo") == "rev_comb")); {classe3_calculolp()};
    else if (document.getElementById("trib_atual").value == "1b" && (document.getElementById("ramo") == "serv_hosp")); {classe4_calculolp()};
    else if (document.getElementById("trib_atual").value == "1b" && (document.getElementById("ramo") == "transp")); {classe5_calculolp()};
 }

 }
 }
 if(document.getElementById("trib_atual").value == "1c") && ((document.getElementById("ramo") == "at_imob") || (document.getElementById("ramo") == "com") || (document.getElementById("ramo") == "ind_terc") || (document.getElementById("ramo") == "transp_cargo")); {classe1_calculolr()};

 else if (document.getElementById("trib_atual").value == "1b" && (document.getElementById("ramo") == "prest_serv")); {classe2_calculolr()};
    else if (document.getElementById("trib_atual").value == "1b" && (document.getElementById("ramo") == "rev_comb")); {classe3_calculolr()};
    else if (document.getElementById("trib_atual").value == "1b" && (document.getElementById("ramo") == "serv_hosp")); {classe4_calculolr()};
    else if (document.getElementById("trib_atual").value == "1b" && (document.getElementById("ramo") == "transp")); {classe5_calculolr()};
 }


 function sera_que_ta_bom(){
    if (opcao_trib == "1a" && ((parseInt(aliquota_simples_nacional) < parseInt(aliq_presumido)) && (parseInt(aliquota_simples_nacional) < parseInt(aliq_real)) 
        || (opcao_trib == "1b" && ((parseInt(aliq_presumido) < parseInt(aliquota_simples_nacional)) && (parseInt(aliq_presumido) < parseInt(aliq_real)) )) 
        || (opcao_trib == "1c" && ((parseInt(aliq_real) < parseInt(aliquota_simples_nacional)) && (parseInt(aliq_real) < parseInt(aliq_presumido)) ) )));
    var resultado = "otimo";

    else if (opcao_trib == "1a" && ((parseInt(aliquota_simples_nacional) > parseInt(aliq_presumido)) && (parseInt(aliquota_simples_nacional) > parseInt(aliq_real)) 
        || (opcao_trib == "1b" && ((parseInt(aliq_presumido) > parseInt(aliquota_simples_nacional)) && (parseInt(aliq_presumido) > parseInt(aliq_real)) )) 
        || (opcao_trib == "1c" && ((parseInt(aliq_real) > parseInt(aliquota_simples_nacional)) && (parseInt(aliq_real) > parseInt(aliq_presumido)) ) )));
    var resultado = "pessimo";
    else var resultado = "meh";
}
 
 }
    function resultado_final(){
        if resultado = "otimo";
        var resultado_final = "Está tudo certo: os números indicam que a empresa está recolhendo tributos de acordo com a média das empresas do setor.";
        else if resultado = "meh";
        var resultado_final = "Ajustes são necessários: é possível que a empresa esteja recolhendo um pouco mais de tributos.";
        else if resultado = "pessimo";
        var resultado_final = "Atenção: tudo indica que a empresa esteja pagando muito mais tributos que outras empresas do setor. Entre em contato com a gente.";

    }
            
            
            

        </script>

    </header>
    <body>

            <p id="one"></p>

        <h1>Calculadora de tributos</h1>

            <form id="form">
                Nome: <input id="nome" type="text" size="15"/> <br/>
                WhatsApp: <input id="whatsapp" type="text" size="15"/> <br/><br/>
                CNPJ: <input id="cnpj" type="text" size="15"/> <br/>
                CNAE: <input id="cnae" type="text" size="15"/> <br/><br/>
                
                Tributação atual: <select id="trib_atual" onblur="opcao_trib()">
                <option id="valor" value=""> </option>
                <option id="valor" value="1a">Simples Nacional</option>
                <option id="valor" value="1b">Lucro Presumido</option>
                <option id="valor" value="1c">Lucro Real</option>
                </select> <br/>
               
                Anexo Simples Nacional: <select id="cat_simples" onblur="opcao_simples()">
                <option id="valor" value=""> </option>
                <option id="valor" value="i">I</option>
                <option id="valor" value="ii">II</option>
                <option id="valor" value="iii">III</option>
                <option id="valor" value="iv">IV</option>
                <option id="valor" value="v">V</option>
                </select> <br/>
                
                Ramo de atividade: <select id="ramo" onblur="opcao_ramo()">
                <option id="valor" value=""> </option>
                <option id="valor" value="at_imob">Atividades imobiliárias</option>
                <option id="valor" value="com">Comércio</option>
                <option id="valor" value="ind_terc">Indústria para terceiros</option>
                <option id="valor" value="prest_serv">Prestação de serviços</option>
                <option id="valor" value="rev_comb">Revenda de combustíveis e gás natural</option>
                <option id="valor" value="serv_hosp">Serviços hospitalares</option>
                <option id="valor" value="transp">Transporte (exceto cargas)</option>
                <option id="valor" value="transp_cargo">Transporte de cargas</option>
                </select> <br/> <br/>
                
                Faturamento do mês: <input id="fat_mensal" type="text" size="15"/> <br/><br/>
               
                Custos com mercadorias/serviços prestados: <input id="custos_merc" type="text" size="15"/> <br/>
               
               
                Despesas gerais: <input id="custos_adm" type="text" size="15"/> <br/>
                Folha mensal (CLT): <input id="custos_clt" type="text" size="15"/> <br/>
                Despesas com marketing: <input id="custos_mkt" type="text" size="15"/> <br/>
                <br/>
                
                
            
                <input id="calcular" type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="resultado_final()"/>
                <input id="limpar" type="reset" value="Resetar"/> <br/> <br/>
                
                Resultado: <input id="resultado_final" type="text" size="15" disabled="true"/>

         </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá!

Você precisa atualizar o elemento da página com o resultado encontrado. Para isso, você necessita capturar esse elemento (pode ser pelo id) e setar o value. Além disso as comparações no IF precisam de 2 sinais de igual.

```
function resultado_final() {
  var resultado_final; 
  if (resultado == "otimo") {
    resultado_final = "Está tudo certo: os números indicam que a empresa está recolhendo tributos de acordo com a média das empresas do setor.";
  } else if (resultado == "meh") {
    resultado_final = "Ajustes são necessários: é possível que a empresa esteja recolhendo um pouco mais de tributos.";
  } else if (resultado == "pessimo") {
    resultado_final = "Atenção: tudo indica que a empresa esteja pagando muito mais tributos que outras empresas do setor. Entre em contato com a gente.";
  }
  // atualiza o elemento da página com o valor encontrado
  document.getElementById('resultado_final').value = resultado_final;
}
```

Comment: Então, acho que essa parte eu consegui ajustar (inclusive saí ajustando os erros no else if). O que agora tá pegando é essa parte aqui, e eu não sei exatamente o que tá errado nela:

```
            function calculo_ir(){
            if (lucro_presumido > 240000){
            var ir = parseInt(lucro_presumido) * 0.15 + (parseInt(lucro_presumido) - 240000) * 0.1;
            } else var ir = parseInt(lucro_presumido) * 0.15;
            }
```

Comment: Aparentemente está com problema nos colchetes. Tente colocar o "else" abaixo do colchete que fecha o "if".

```function calculo_ir(){
  if (lucro_presumido > 240000) {
    var ir = parseInt(lucro_presumido) * 0.15 + (parseInt(lucro_presumido) - 240000) * 0.1;
  }
  else {
    var ir = parseInt(lucro_presumido) * 0.15;
  } 
}```

Comment: Uma coisa que reparei, você está declarando variáveis dentro da função, mas não está utilizando para nada, lembre-se que se declarar uma variável dentro da função ela não é vista do "lado de fora"

Comment: Sim, eu estou ajustando. Mas boa parte das variáveis é usada só dentro da função mesmo. Vi agora que uma das funções eu não terminei porque a fórmula do excel tava cheia de IFs, mas acho que agora tá dando certo. Muito obrigada pela ajuda!